# Chapter I of Gelfand and Fomin's Calculus on Variations: a couple of questions

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, definition, mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations

I'm struggling to understand some concepts in the first half of the first chapter of Gelfand and Fomin's *Calculus of Variations*. I want to make sure the defintions and theorem I wrote below are the same as the authors'.

---

**Definition:** let $C^1[a,b]$ be the collection of differentiable functions $[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ with continuous derivative. The space forms a vector space with the natural operations inherited from $\mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, the map $||\cdot||_1:C^1[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$y\mapsto ||y||_1 := \sup_{a\le x\le b} |y(x)| + \sup_{a\le x\le b}|y'(x)|$$
is a norm on $C^1[a,b]$, providing it with the structure of a normed vector space, and thus of a topological space.

**Definition:** a functional $J:C^1[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is *continuous* if it is continuous with respect to the topology provided on $C^1[a,b]$ by its norm, and the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$. We say $J$ is *differentiable* at $y\in C^1[a,b]$ if its [Fréchet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Definition) exists at that point, in which case we denote it by $\delta_y J$.

**Question:** are these definitions correct i.e. are they equivalent to the definitions provided in the text?

---

**Theorem:** for a fixed $C^2$ function $F:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ we define the functional
$$J:C^1[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}:y\mapsto\int_b^aF(x,y,y')\ dx.$$
Then $J$ is differentiable at any $y\in C^1[a,b]$ with
$$\delta_yJ:h\mapsto\int_b^a\left[F_y(x,y,y')h+F_{y'}(x,y,y')h'\right]\ dx.$$

**Question:** is this is the formal statement of the result stated in pages 14 and 15 of the text (image below)?

[image]
[image]

Comment: yes that’s essentially it, but they haven’t (atleast not in the screenshot you gave) proven Frechet differentiability (because they didn’t even mention the norm on the function space anywhere). If you want a slightly more formal treatment, see Henri Cartan’s *Differential Forms*, he has a chapter on calculus of variations. The only thing to keep in mind is that Cartan writes $f’(a)$ for the Frechet derivative (instead of my preferred notation $Df_a$, or $\delta_af$ as you write here).

Comment: @peek-a-boo If not the Fréchet derivative, then what is meant by $\delta J$ in the picture?

Comment: I mean that they did not rigorously prove that the thing they wrote is the Frechet derivative. They gave a vague allusion to Taylor’s theorem but did not give proper estimates for the error. So though the final answer is right, there are steps to be filled in (see Cartan, or Loomis snd Sternberg, the later parts of chapter 3).