# Step in Proof at the beginning of Gelfand and Fomin's

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation, calculus-of-variations

This is a follow up to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4739183/chapter-i-of-gelfand-and-fomins-calculus-on-variations-a-couple-of-questions).

In the proof below (from Gelfand and Fomin's *Calculus of Variations*), how exactly is Taylor's Theorem used to derive the equality
$$\triangle J = \int^b_a[F_y(x,y,y')h+F_{y'}(x,y,y')h']dx + \dots?$$

[image]
[image]

Comment: Expand $F$ at the point $(x,y,y')$. Keep the terms up to order $1$. The order zero term is $F(x,y,y')$, which cancels with the $-F(x,y,y')$. The order $1$ term with coefficient $F_x(x,y,y')$ appears multiplied by the increment in the first coordinate, which is zero. That is why it is not present. The other two order $1$ terms are the ones they kept. The $\ldots$ is the (integral of the) remainder. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables) to compare, where their $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(x,y,y')$ and $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x,y+h,y'+h')$.