# Proving the differential of $y\mapsto\int_b^aF(x,y,y')\ dx$ is given by $h\mapsto\int_b^a\left[F_y(x,y,y')h+F_{y'}(x,y,y')h'\right]\ dx$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, calculus-of-variations

Follow up to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4739183/chapter-i-of-gelfand-and-fomins-calculus-on-variations-a-couple-of-questions). **Is my attempt at a proof of the theorem below correct?**

---

**Definition:** let $C^1[a,b]$ be the collection of differentiable functions $[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ with continuous derivative. The space forms a vector space with the natural operations inherited from $\mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, the map $||\cdot||_1:C^1[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$y\mapsto ||y||_1 := \sup_{a\le x\le b} |y(x)| + \sup_{a\le x\le b}|y'(x)|$$
is a norm on $C^1[a,b]$, providing it with the structure of a normed vector space, and thus of a topological space.

**Definition:** a functional $J:C^1[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is *continuous* if it is continuous with respect to the topology provided on $C^1[a,b]$ by its norm, and the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$. We say $J$ is *differentiable* at $y\in C^1[a,b]$ if its [Fréchet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Definition) exists at that point, in which case we denote it by $\delta_y J$.

---

**Theorem:** for a fixed $C^2$ function $F:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ we define the functional
$$J:C^1[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}:y\mapsto\int_b^aF(x,y,y')\ dx.$$
Then $J$ is differentiable at any $y\in C^1[a,b]$ with
$$\delta_yJ:h\mapsto\int_b^a\left[F_y(x,y,y')h+F_{y'}(x,y,y')h'\right]\ dx.$$

***Proof (my attempt):*** by Taylor's Theorem we may write $F(t,y+h,y'+h')$ as
\begin{split}
& \ F(t,y,y')+\sum_{|\alpha|=1}\partial_\alpha F(t,y,y')\mathbf{h}^\alpha + R_{\mathbf{a},k}(\mathbf{h})\\
= & \ F(t,y,y')+\partial_2 F(t,y,y')h + \partial_3 F(t,y,y')h' + R_{\mathbf{a},k}(\mathbf{h})
\end{split}
for $\mathbf{a}=(t,y,y')$ and $\mathbf{h}=(0,h,h')$. We thus have
\begin{split}
J(y+h)-J(y) & = \int_a^b\Bigg[F(t,y+h,y'+h')-F(t,y,y')\Bigg]\ dt\\
& = \int_a^b\Bigg[\partial_2 F(t,y,y')h + \partial_3 F(t,y,y')h'\Bigg]\ dt + \int_a^bR_{\mathbf{a},k}(\mathbf{h})\ dt
\end{split}
and it remains to be shown that
$$\lim_{\|h\|\to 0}\frac{\int_a^bR_{\mathbf{a},k}(\mathbf{h})\ dt}{\|h\|}\to 0$$
where the remainder $R_{\mathbf{a},k}(\mathbf{h})$ takes the form
$$\sum_{|\alpha|=2}\frac{\partial_\alpha F(t,y+c_{\alpha,t}h,y'+c_{\alpha,t}h')}{\alpha!}\mathbf{h}^\alpha.$$
Letting
$$r=\sup\bigg\{\|\left(t,y+c_{\alpha,t}h,y'+c_{\alpha,t}h'\right)\| : t\in[a,b]\bigg\}$$
then, for any $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|=2$, the function $\partial_\alpha F$ is continuous on the closed ball $B_r(0)$ (of radius $r$, centered at $0$) and thus attains its maximum $M_\alpha$ somewhere on such set. If we let $M=\sup_{\alpha}M_\alpha$, then
\begin{split}
\frac{1}{\|h\|}\int_a^bR_{\mathbf{a},k}(\mathbf{h})\ dt
& \le \frac{1}{\|h\|}\int_a^b\sum_{|\alpha|=2}M\mathbf{h}^\alpha\ dt\\
& = \frac{M}{\|h\|}\int_a^b\bigg[h^2+2hh'+(h')^2\bigg]\ dt\\
& \le \frac{M}{\|h\|}\int_a^b\|h\|^2\ dt\\
& = M(b-a)\|h\|
\end{split}
which tends to $0$ as $\|h\|\to 0$.

Comment: I do not understand where the expression for the remainder comes from, should there not be some kind of integral like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor's_theorem_for_multivariate_functions)?